# Graph in Python 3.5.2 with Greek Letters (LaTeX)

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, latex

I am Python newbie and trying to reproduce the following graph:

[image]

MWE is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='green',
                            alpha=0.75)
# add a 'best fit' line
y = mlab.normpdf( bins, mu, sigma)
l = plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--', linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel('Smarts')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title(r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ IQ:}\ \mu=100,\ \sigma=15$')
plt.axis([40, 160, 0, 0.03])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

And output is:

[image]

However, Greek letters are not rending properly. I might be missing something basic here. How can I reproduce the original graph in Python 3.5.2?

**Edited**

I using Python 3.5.2 through Python 2.4.1 and IDLE on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Using Python 3.5.2 through IPython/Anaconda (and tested through idle too). It works perfectly fine when copying your code into my prompt. From where do you run yours?

Comment: @internetional: Please see my edits. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: I would try IPython if I was you. I find it more stable than IDLE. Sadly I have few clues and even fewer ideas on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the font in `matplotlibrc`to change the latex font if rendering isnt okay :

```
from matplotlib import rc

rc('font', **{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

or simply:

```
 plt.title("Histogram of IQ: " r'$\mu = 100, \sigma$ =15')
```

Sample output of the title:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Achilles for your answer. I used `from matplotlib import rc` after `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. But still have the same problem. Any thoughts.

Comment: I am using `plt.title(r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ IQ:}\ \mu=100,\ \sigma=15$')`.

Comment: Check it now , i even showed the sample output of the label

Comment: plt.title("Histogram of IQ: " r'$\mu = 100, \sigma$ =15')

Comment: Thanks @Achilles for your help and time. However, it is not working on my machine yet.

Comment: Well, i now tried your code modified the title and got what you wanted. Maybe you dont have the font